# Querying the 2nd Line from a command output in Perl

Tags: perl

I need to query on the 2nd line which I am seeing in the output. I need to check if the command returns on "Listener LISTENER is running on" and provide the desired output. My code is able to read the first line and not the second line which I need to verify. Please advise.

```
srvctl status listener
Listener LISTENER is enabled
Listener LISTENER is running on node(s): XYZ
```

I tried updating the code to read the second line and did not work.

```
my $cmd="srvctl status listener";
my $listenerstatus0;
my $msg0;
my $msg1;
open(Row1Stat,"$cmd |") || die ("Could not read the pipe\n");
$listenerstatus0 = <Row1Stat>;
close(Row1Stat);
while (<>){
if( $listenerstatus0 =~ m/Listener LISTENER is running/)
{
$msg0="LISTENER is running";
$msg1=1
}
elsif ($listenerstatus0 =~ m/Listener LISTENER is not running/) {
$msg0 = "LISTENER is not running";
$msg1 = 0;
}
else {
$msg0 = "Unable to Query LISTENER Status";
$msg1 = 0;
}
}

print "\nStatistic.Name1:$msg1";
print "\nMessage.Name1:$msg0";
```

I should be able to read Listener LISTENER is running on node(s): XYZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading only the first line from the pipe. You either need a loop (`while <Row1Stat>) { ... }`) and read all lines one at a time, or read the whole pipe contents in one go, e.g., by `local $/ = undef;`, which clears the [input record separator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#IO::Handle-%3Einput_record_separator(-EXPR-)) (by default a newline).

Here's an example reading in a loop. I've removed the pipe to make it a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example, since the `srvctl` command is not really necessary.

```
use strict; 
use warnings;

my $msg0 = "not running";
my $msg1 = 0;

while (<DATA>) {
    if (m/Listener LISTENER is running/) {
        $msg0 = "is running";
        $msg1 = 1;
    }
    elsif (m/Listener LISTENER is enabled/) {
        $msg0 = "is enabled";
        $msg1 = 2;
    }
}

print "Statistic.Name1:$msg1\n";
print "Message.Name1:$msg0\n";

__DATA__
srvctl status listener
Listener LISTENER is enabled
Listener LISTENER is running on node(s): XYZ
```

You cannot use an `else` block to set "not running" cause you're reading line by line and don't want to override your found line later. Hence I initialize this when I declare the variables.

Now for slurping the whole pipe output and working on that:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $msg0;
my $msg1;

local $/ = undef;
my $data = <DATA>;

if ($data =~ m/Listener LISTENER is running/) {
    $msg0 = "is running";
    $msg1 = 1;
}
elsif ($data =~ m/Listener LISTENER is enabled/) {
    $msg0 = "is enabled";
    $msg1 = 2;
}
else {
    my $msg0 = "not running";
    my $msg1 = 0;
}

print "Statistic.Name1:$msg1\n";
print "Message.Name1:$msg0\n";

__DATA__
srvctl status listener
Listener LISTENER is enabled
Listener LISTENER is running on node(s): XYZ
```

In both cases you need to decide which line ("LISTENER is enabled" or "LISTENER is running") is more important to you. When reading line by line, add a check that you don't overwrite your variables with the less important message. When slurping, adjust the order of the checks (`if`s) so that the most important one goes first.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I updated the code as per suggestions provided by you, however it still does not work. I am interested only if the LISTENER is running or not running which is displayed in the second row. Can you please let me know, why this is failing.

Comment: @ArnabMukhopadhyay Sorry, I cannot. I have no idea what your code looks like. I have no idea what you mean by "does not work". I'd suggest you `print` what you read from the pipe to see that you're looking at the right data, i.e., you're reading beyond the first line. If the data you get looks right, check your regular expressions.

Comment: Hi, I updated the code in the original question. I am not sure how to leverage the while loop in my case. I need to run the $cmd since I am querying the 2nd line. I see you used _DATA_ however this is not a file I am reading from.

Comment: @ArnabMukhopadhyay `<DATA>` is a special file handle for the `__DATA__` section. Reading from the pipe works the same. You are still only reading the first line. Check again on my answer above. Either slurp the whole file by undefining `$/` before you read, or have a loop and read multiple lines.

Comment: HI, I tried both the options and did not work.                                    Option 2                       local $/ = undef;
                                     $listenerstatus0 = <Row1Stat>;                    Option 1  While Loop    while (<$cmd>) { }.